# How can I read an array from a XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

At the moment I got this:

```
class robot
{
    Configuratie config = new Configuratie();
    short[,] AlleCoordinaten = new short[3, 6] 
    {
        {1,2,3,4,5,6},
        {6,5,4,3,2,1},
        {2,3,4,5,6,7}
    };
}
```

But I want to put that array in a XML-file, so this is what I tried:

```
class robot
{
Configuratie config = new Configuratie();

    short[,] AlleCoordinaten = new short[3, 6] 
    {
        {(config.GetIntConfig("robot","position1"))},
        {(config.GetIntConfig("robot","position2"))},
        {(config.GetIntConfig("robot","position3"))}
    }; 
}
```

configuration file:

```
    class Configuratie
    {
        private XDocument xdoc;

        public Configuratie()
        {
            xdoc = XDocument.Load("configuratie.xml");
        }
    public int GetIntConfig(string desc1, string desc2)
    {
        int value = 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc1))
        {
            value = 0;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc2))
        {
            foreach (XElement node in xdoc.Descendants(desc1).Descendants(desc2))
            {
                value = Convert.ToInt16(node.Value);
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc2))
        {  
            foreach (XElement node in xdoc.Descendants(desc1))
            {
                value = Convert.ToInt16(node.Value);
            }
        }
        return value;
        }
    }
```

XML file:

```
<robot>
<position1>1</position1>
<position1>2</position1>
<position1>3</position1>
<position1>4</position1>
<position1>5</position1>
<position1>6</position1>
etc...
<position3>7</position3>
</robot>
```

It still isn't working, could you guys help me with what I did wrong and maybe give an example. The errors i got are: The error I get is: an array initializer of length 6 is expected. And: a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property. I know there is an easier way, but I want to do it with the configuration file. 
How can I do this ?

Comment: I have already answered this question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21552800/3010968

Comment: Your array initialization is screwed up. The compiler is actually telling you this. `GetIntConfig()` returns an `int` which you are passing into an array which expects an item with 6 integers. Not one. The second error is because you are using an instance variable to set up another instance variable, what happens if the compiler re-arranges the order in which they are intitialized? Then you potentially access a variable which hasn't been set so this is not allowed either.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you ment put (like to build an XML from that data).
This is how to do so:

`short[,] AlleCoordinaten = new short[3, 6] 
    {
         {1,2,3,4,5,6},
         {6,5,4,3,2,1},
         {2,3,4,5,6,7}
    };

        XElement elem = new XElement("robot");
        for (int i = 0; i < AlleCoordinaten.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < AlleCoordinaten.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                elem.Add(new XElement(string.Format("position{0}",i +1),AlleCoordinaten.GetValue(i,j)));
            }
        }`

Comment: thanks for your awnser, im almost there now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552500/reading-an-array-from-an-xml-file. The only problem left is that 'The name 'AlleCoordinaten' does not exist in the currect content'

Answer (score -2):

I see a simple typo here:

```
config.GetIntConfig("robot","positoin1")
```

So You're looking for "positoin" and in the file You got "position".